# MYSQL update statement with valid criteria does nothing

Tags: mysql, sql

I really need some insight on this one as I have no idea what is going on. I've been looking around for days and it still doesn't work.

I have a table of events having multiple columns with different informations. The goal is to export this table in a csv file to import in an another db.

before exporting, I want to correct the format of a specific column data(including some basic html for a cms). 
Based on the select query, the criteria work perfectly and return the 68 records I am looking to update. Those are a part of the data, some other update have much more records.

SELECT query:

```
select *
from `tblevents`
where `eventfree`='Finishers medal
T-Shirt
Free beer ticket';
```

But the update query with the same criteria, updates nothing. It doesn't return any error, but update nothing...

```
update `tblevents`
set `eventfree`='<ul>
    <li>Finishers medal</li>
    <li>T-Shirt</li>
    <li>Free beer ticket</li>
</ul>'
where `eventfree`='Finishers medal
T-Shirt
Free beer ticket';
```

I'm executing this in the SQL tab of phpMyAdmin...it's driving me crazy as it should be straight forward...

Thanks

Comment: take notice of the different quotes firstly - ` and '

Comment: The quotes are fine, but it might be related to the white spaces (line breaks) used in the query. phpMyAdmin might trim them automatically.

Comment: yeah the different quotes don't really change anything...i did gave it a try. I'm also leaning toward the line breaks...but is there any way to go around this? and at the same time...the select return the rows with the same where clause.

Comment: Try changing your where clause to use the id of the entry you want to change. e.g. WHERE eventfreeId = 10; As MVP mentions, there could be significant white-space in your WHERE clause that causes the update to fail.

Comment: I dont' see whitespace there, wait

Comment: try to remove ul and html tag ...

Comment: what MVP told did light up something....phpMyAdmin is indeed the problem. I ran the query in the mySql console and it works...so for some reason phpMyAdmin is messing up the update statement.